# How do I register trigger bindings in an Azure Function (v2, .net core)?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to create a durable function, so I have one function with a serviceBusTrigger, one with an orchestrationTrigger, and one with an activityTrigger. I'm doing something wrong in terms of registering the trigger bindings.

When I run locally, I get the following error:

> No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods
>   public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage,
>   ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration
>   method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   build.AddAzureStorage(), build.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(),
>   etc.).
>
> The following 3 functions are in error:
>
> : The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type
>   is correct and the binding extension is installed.
>
> : The
>   binding type(s) 'orchestrationTrigger' are not registered. Please
>   ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.
>
> : The binding type(s) 'activityTrigger' are not
>   registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding
>   extension is installed.

In .net core functions, it's my understanding that there is no startup file to expressly register the bindings in code. Instead, I've just installed the nuget packages that correspond to each type of trigger.

For example reference, here is my serviceBusTrigger function:

```
[FunctionName("Function_HttpStart")]
public static async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("my-queuename", Connection = "ConnectionString")] RequestObject request,
    [OrchestrationClient]DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    var instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("OtherFunction", request);

    log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
}
```

and the function.json file that gets generated:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.24",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "connection": "ConnectionString",
      "queueName": "my-queueName",
      "name": "request"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/x.dll",
  "entryPoint": "Namespace.Project.Run"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure we don't install the package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator` separately. It's a package referenced by `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`, installing it explicitly makes the `[FunctionProject]\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\extensions.json` file(containing the binding extensions info) fail to generate.

The project file(right click on project, `Edit [FunctionProject].csproj`) should look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Well, I had Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.ServiceBus installed instead of Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extensions.ServiceBus. This is perfect, thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue as OP. My csproj file looks like what you said it should (albeit with newer versions of each package) but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, installing package named:

`Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extensions.ServiceBus`

instead of:

`Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.ServiceBus`

...helped solving the problem.